# Exporting a constant with a dynamic name in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to export a constant with a dynamic name in es6?

e.g:

```
const NAME = 'abc';
const foo = 'bar';
export {foo as NAME}
```

Comment: Can't do, ES6 modules are static.

Comment: why not import it as whatever you want to call it?

Comment: @elclanrs is correct, the ES2015 module spec is specifically designed to not allow for dynamic imports and exports. There are good reasons for this: http://calculist.org/blog/2012/06/29/static-module-resolution/

Comment: Why would you want to do that anyway? What is your problem? Wouldn't this complicate the import if the name was changing?